# php print specific value of nested array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I'm trying to print out a value in an array based on the email address of current user within WordPress.  The array has been setup with

```
$link= json_decode($xml, TRUE);
```

I have some basic logic to check the current WordPRess user's email and print it out.

```
if (in_array("current_user->user_email", $link)) {
    echo "Got user's email address:" .'<br />';
    echo $current_user->user_email;
    echo "<br />";
    echo $Members->MemberID;
} else {
    echo "No such email address exists";
}
```

I also need to print out the Member ID value of that current user from the array. Here is a sample output of that array. Is this even possible?  I'm trying to do this without having to store any data within a database.

```
 Array
 (
 [Members] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [EmailAddress] =>randomemail@gmail.com
                [FirstName] => Merle
                [LastName] => Delisio
                [MemberExtension] => 000
                [MemberID] => c1c17b39-bdba-4c76-9fd6-e53a982aa713
                [MemberNumber] => 2031
                [MiddleInitial] => 

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [EmailAddress] => someemail@gmail.com
                [FirstName] => Allen
                [LastName] => Barnaby
                [MemberExtension] => 000
                [MemberID] => 2e16fded-e55b-4687-9696-eb329b96d1e7
                [MemberNumber] => 2001
                [MiddleInitial] =>
```

Comment: search "php array traversal" in google to find useful information on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

Multi dimensional array search may be what you're looking for?

### http://www.highonphp.com/multidimensional-array-search

I'm not sure if this will get you exactly what you need, but hopefully will help point you in the right direction.

```
if (in_array("current_user->user_email", $link)) {
    echo "Got user's email address:" .'<br />';
    echo $current_user->user_email;
    echo "<br />";
    $tmp = array_multi_search($Members, $current_user->user_email);
    echo $Members[$tmp[0]]['MemberID'];
} else {
    echo "No such email address exists";
}
```

In your example, $Members is an array of arrays. If you were to use something like that example array_multi_search, if `$current_user->user_email = 'someemail@gmail.com'` I would expect to get `$tmp = array(0 => 0)`. With your given $Members example, we would really only ever expect to get one value returned. I hope the rest is self explanatory, if not, lemme know.

Comment: What do I set for the second parameter @input,  "MemberID"?  Also having trouble with how to call the function so that I get the value of MemberID returned.  The example in your link uses print_r which returns the array.

Comment: Hope that helps some.

Comment: It definitely does not hurt.  I think it's more my inability to wrap my head around the concept of recursiveness.  Your code seems to be getting caught up with 
$tmp = array_multi_search($Members, $current_user->user_email);
I'm getting "Call to undefined function Array_Multi_Search". 
Could it be something to do with the $current_user variable which is part of the WordPress function  wp_get_current_user()?

Comment: Yeah, you'll need to copy/paste that function from the link somewhere accessible to your code.

Comment: Oh, and now that you mention this is WordPress related, there may be a better way to get this information already.

Comment: Well I'm getting closer.  I believe I just need help with one last thing.  I have the array_multi_search returning just one array in the nested array based on the wordpress user's email.  But now I need to extract one value from that array.  I'm having trouble accessing it using:
$tmparray = print_r(array_multi_search($link, $MailAddy), true);
 

echo $tmparray[0]['MemberID'];